# Presto not returning rows from Hive Metabase

Tags: hadoop, hive, presto

I'm very new to AWS EMR. I've got Hive up and running and been querying external tables in S3 with no problems. I have now installed Presto onto the EMR cluster and this seems to be up and running and can read the Hive metabase. However, every query I run returns the column headers but not actually any columns (query below).

```
presto:default> select count(*) from patrequests;
 _col0
-------
     0
(1 row)

Query 20171113_163811_00033_vdw6c, FINISHED, 1 node
Splits: 17 total, 17 done (100.00%)
0:00 [0 rows, 0B] [0 rows/s, 0B/s]
```

The same query in Hive runs fine:

```
hive> select * from patrequests limit 10;
OK
2017-10-01T00:00:18.6772628Z    779     *****  *****  *****      *****      2017    10
Time taken: 2.876 seconds, Fetched: 10 row(s)
```

The data is stored in an S3 bucket in JSON format - no nesting.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hive has a _MetaStore_ service, backed by a _database_ -- but there is no such thing as a _MetaBase_...

Comment: Beware: some *#!\&** has decided, years ago, that Hive should give wrong results for all `count(*)` queries. Don't ask me why. But it is done by using "statistics" i.e. a value that was plausible at some point in the past, but certainly ridiculously off the mark when _you_ run the query now. OK, returning a wrong result is very fast, but it is wrong.

Comment: My 2 cents: try sthg like  `select count(*) from WTF where ID is not null` (cannot use crude "statistics" for that) to see if the query actually fetches the data to compute a valid result...

Comment: Sorry, I mean the Hive Metastore which Presto can see. However, the problem is not with Hive is is with Presto not returning results.

I have tried running on a non-aggregate select but it still doesn't return anything. Could it be an issue with the underlying data that Presto doesn't like?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to be with the JSON Serde org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe not being available to Presto. Bootstrapping the instance with the following from an S3 bucket seemed to resolve the issues:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget -P /usr/lib/presto/plugin/hive-hadoop2/  'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/########/json-serde-1.3.9-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar';
wget -P /usr/lib/hive-hcatalog/share/hcatalog/ 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/########/json-serde-1.3.9-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar';
```